# Setting an Analytics user segment

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'd like to understand setting up Analytics Segments better.

Assume I set up a filter like in the example on the screenshot.

Will this segment include all of the users that ever made an Event with a "Download" action?
If so, how long will it remember that a user made a "Download" Action?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segment will include users who have made a "Download" event action during the period of time you have selected in the web UI. This is different from users who have EVER performed that action. If you want to find out users during the lifetime of the site, then you would just increase the date range.

Note that since users are tracked via cookies, if the person clears their cookie or switch to a different browser, then they will be counted multiple times. Also when you increase your date range, you are likely to be hit with sampling.